# How to assign different ip's on cloned systems (no VM's, embedded systems)

Tags: ip, dhcp, cloning

After some research, I am not being able to solve assigning different ip's on cloned systems. Most questions reference working on VM's.

I have an embedded system, I will call it Master: Google Coral, OS: Mendel GNU/Linux 5 (Eagle). I then use other Google Corals to make a clone of the main system (with `dd`). If all are connected to the same wifi (wlan0), the ip for both (master and slave/slaves) remains the same. This means that connecting via ssh (as an example) is impossible to do in all the clones and master. It will connect to one of them only. This is assuming all of them will be connected to the same wifi network!

I have tried with proposed solutions like [dbus-uuidgen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402999/is-it-ok-to-change-etc-machine-id) and [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/655670/two-virtualbox-vms-running-in-parallel-assigned-same-ip) , removing `/etc/machine_id`, following the steps, and also installing [netplan](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034711/how-to-enable-netplan-on-ubuntu-server-upgraded-from-16-04-to-18-04) to specify dhcp to mac. No positive results so far. I checked [dhcp to assign static ip's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/637640/using-dhcpcd-to-assign-a-static-ip-address-on-debian) and [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131031/is-it-possible-for-dhcp-to-assign-different-ip-addresses-to-the-same-machine) but I think it does not go to the point I want. The following code from netplan in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/655670/two-virtualbox-vms-running-in-parallel-assigned-same-ip).

```
  dhcp4: yes
  dhcp-identifier: mac
```

But after installing `netplan.io`, there is no file for the netplan config. I have seen the name of the file changes depending on the system used. Maybe I need to add something to `dhcpserver`, like in [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391977/how-to-get-different-ips-on-cloned-machines-with-virtualbox)? I thought of changing [hostnamectl](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ubuntu-20-04-change-hostname) in case that was also a main identifier for ip assigning, but it does not matter. It is irrelevant for me if users have the same name. But by doing a clone, it remains the same. The same with pretty-name.

Is there any way to have cloned systems, connected to the same network, and having different ip's for each system? My knowledge on networking is not proficient. Apologies in advanced.

Comment: When cloning a VirtualBox VM using the VirtualBox GUI, one usually get an option to set a new MAC address on the clone, which would prompt the DHCP server to give the clone a different IP address (as DHCP servers use the MAC address to identify the host). But I don't know what type of VM you're dealing with or what software you usually use to administrate the virtual machines.

Comment: not related to virtual machines! separate embedded systems, that have the same architecture. @Kusalananda

Comment: Ah, then I misunderstood the context(probably due to sloppy reading). Your recent edit is good!